# PHPUnit installed but simply doing nothing

Tags: macos, configuration, installation, phpunit

I am following along with the tutorials in 'Easy PHP Websites with Zend Framework' and wanted to install PHPUnit.

System: Mac OS x Lion, PHP running locally (Not MAMP)

Pear was installed and working fine, I upgraded it to the latest.

Installed PHPUnit using

```
sudo pear install phpunit/PHPUnit
```

terminal did some work and installed it without errors

The in my terminal I did

```
phpunit --version
```

this returns/does nothing as follows (Username removed)

```
Machine:~ Username$ phpunit --version
Machine:~ Username$ sudo phpunit --version
Machine:~ Username$
```

Was worried it some how did not install so I check for the PHPUnit files and they do exist under /usr/lib/php/phpunit

Also checked that the phpunit exe exists which it does under /usr/bin

edited .profile as well as .bash_profile to include the /usr/bin path to have

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
```

then restarted terminal

running

```
echo $PATH
```

shows

```
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/xxxxx/development/frameworks/ZendFramework-1.11.11/bin
```

php.ini includes is

```
include_path = ".:/usr/lib/php/pear:/Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/ZendFramework-1.11.11/library"
```

Where xxxxx is my username on the Mac

even going into /usr/bin in terminal and using phpunit --version returns nothing

in case its relevant my PEAR config shows

```
Configuration (channel pear.php.net):
=====================================
...
...
PEAR executables directory     bin_dir          /usr/bin
PEAR documentation directory   doc_dir          /usr/lib/php/doc
PHP extension directory        ext_dir          /usr/lib/php/extensions/.....
PEAR directory                 php_dir          /usr/lib/php
PEAR data directory            data_dir         /usr/lib/php/data
PHP CLI/CGI binary             php_bin          /usr/bin/php
php.ini location               php_ini          <not set>
....
....
PEAR Installer temp directory  temp_dir         /private/tmp/pear/temp
PEAR test directory            test_dir         /usr/lib/php/test
PEAR www files directory       www_dir          /usr/lib/php/htdocs
....
```

Also added the pear and phpunit directory to my php.ini includes path list.

Am at a loss as to why this does not want to work. Am sure its me and I have done something incorrectly....Any help appreciated.

Comment: To elimintate a path issue, does `/usr/lib/php/phpunit --version` also not output anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, solved this, finally after much reading and fiddling. Issue was with PEAR, not PHPUnit itself.

Found the issue by following the set up for PEAR onhttp://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.checking.php

php.ini change from

.:/usr/lib/php/pear:/Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/ZendFramework-1.11.11/library:/usr/lib/php/PHPUnit

to

.:/usr/lib/php/pear:/Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/ZendFramework-1.11.11/library:/usr/lib/php

solved this issue immediately.

phpunit --version now works